# ImportError: No module named flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

Подскажите плиз куда копать.

Создал окружение, проинсталил туда Flask.
В нем вот файл - main.py

---

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == 'main':
    app.run()
```

Запускаю, получаю:

> from flask import Flask
>   ImportError: No module named flask

`(env) $ pip list`

> - click        6.7
> - Flask        1.0.2
> - itsdangerous 0.24
> - Jinja2       2.10
> - MarkupSafe   1.0
> - pip          18.0
> - setuptools   40.0.0
> - Werkzeug     0.14.1
> - wheel        0.31.1

Comment: Как запускаете-то?

Comment: В VS Code, локально. Code открываю из терминала из активированного окружения.

Comment: А если запускать не в VS Code, а в терминале?

Comment: Если в глобале запускаю, все работает. В env нет.

Comment: как именно вы запускаете проект в vscode? через внутр. терминал, по кнопке... не понятно же

Answer (score -1):

скачай flask через команду в терминале pip install flask

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Надо создать ещё страницу через декоратор `app.route`.

пример:

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    #Здесь пишешь адрес страницы
    @app.route('/home')# Например
    def home():
        return 'hello world'
    if __name__ == 'main':
        app.run()
```

если не сработает, значит ошибка в установке.